# Spyder 5.1.5: is there a way to get the @ button back to the toolbar? or a shortcut to quickly access a function inside a very long code?

Tags: python, spyder

I am wondering if anybody knows how to get the @ back to the toolbar in Spyder 5.1.5. I used to use that a lot when searching for functions in long codes of mine. Recently, I updated to the most recent version of Spyder and could not find @ anywhere. Now, I need to scroll down a lot to see where the functions I am looking for are.

Using find is also OK, but for that, it is better to remember the name of the function correctly. So, this makes searching and finding last a lot longer than using one click to the @ button.

Any ideas of how to get the @ back?

Or does anybody use any other tool/shortcut to access the functions inside a very long code?
Thanks in advance.